# Unable to properly form MySQL query (or subquery)

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query that I just can't seem to get right.  The table isn't terribly complicated.  The fields I have are Name and 2 FacebookUserIDs.  I am having a referral contest.  The first FbookUId is the ID of the person who entered the contest, and the referral ID is the ID of the user who referred them.
I want to select each of the primary fbookUIDs and count the number of referrals that person is responsible for.  Here is the query I've tried:

I've made an update:  Here is a some simple sample data I created:

```
INSERT INTO facebookContest
(name, FacebookID, FacebookReferalID)
VALUES
('Joe', '10', '1'),
('Sam', '20', '5'),
('Mary', '30', '20'),
('Jim', '40', '20'),
('Mike', '50', '100'),
('Bob', '60', '100');
```

My query:

```
SELECT name, FacebookID, COUNT(FacebookReferalID) FROM facebookContest GROUP BY FacebookReferalID
```

Here is the result of my query, which clearly isn't right:

```
NAME    FACEBOOKID  COUNT(FACEBOOKREFERALID)
Joe 10  1
Sam 20  1
Mary    30  2
Mike    50  2
```

Mary and Mike do not have any referrals, but are given credit for 2 each.  I'd like to have every unique Facebook ID be returned in my query.  Only 4 out of 6 are being returned.

```
SELECT *, COUNT (FacebookReferalID) FROM facebookContest GROUP BY FacebookID
```

I'm thinking I might need a subquery, but I'm not that much of an SQL expert to put it together.
Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you showed sample data and the results you expect from it.

Comment: just as a side, its probably just a typo on your question, but i believe the syntax should be `facebookContent.*, COUNT (FacebookReferalID)` not `*, COUNT (FacebookReferalID)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/327b7/4/0

Isn't it exactly what you need?